# OLD Am Standard tank valve repair/replacement?

Tags: repair, toilet

I have an old American Standard toilet and there is a slow leak between the tank and the bowl.  I replaced the N-3055 feather valve and the slow leak remains. The metal seat feels smooth but looks like it might have tiny nicks or corrosion.  Since it was not leaking before I changed the feather valve, I am thinking that the replacement feather valve was old and warped.  (I bought the replacement from a plumbing store on ebay.)

Should I buy another feather valve from another plumbing supply store?

Should I replace the metal seat (which would be a bit of a pain, and I do not know how to replace it).

Is there a replacement kit that would take care of my problem with minimal effort?

Thanks.
[image: seat with tiny nicks]
[image: whole tank]
[image]

Comment: Where is the leak? If it's where you stated 'between the tank and bowl' which I understand as leaking out between the tank and bowl to the floor, then you'd have to take off the bowl and replace the gasket between them, and has nothing to do with inside the tank.

Comment: The leak was through the feather valve.  I finally replaced the old feather valve assembly. It was a pain, since the bolts holding the tank on the bowl were old and frozen.